# YII transaction on multiple model

Tags: php, yii

YII transaction on multiple model
Can you provide me example of yii transaction on multiple model
Like user model and post model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the sample of using transactions with models:

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try
{
    $post= new Post;
    //set attributes
    $post->save();
    $user = new User;
    //set attributes;
    $user->save();
    $transaction->commit();
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
    $transaction->rollBack();
 }
```

When you use transaction, all codes inside try block considered as **one transction** and if saving of each record fail for any reason, transaction rolls back.
For more information about transactions and Active Record you can follow [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#using-transaction-with-ar).